# How to determine where the CCK fields are stored in database?

Tags: 6, entities, database

When a **content type** is created, there is a new table for it. For example, there is a `content_type_claim` table, for content type `claim`. **Content fields** are defined within the table.

However, when a **content field** is shared (used more than once) in different **content types**, there will be another table created for this field. For example, there is a `content_field_claim_no` table for `claim no`, if `claim no` is also used in another content type.

My question is, in which table Drupal defines whether a **content type field** is stored inside the `content_type_???` table (when used once), or in its own `conten_field_???` table (when used more than once), for a particular `content type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `content_node_field_instance` table. As that table defines each "instance" of a field on different content types. For the field configurations (global configs, independent of instance configs) you want the `content_node_field` table.

Similarly in Drupal 7 there's `field_config` table for global field configurations, and `field_config_instance` table for each instance of a field with content types.

Comment: Looks like the `db_storage` field in `content_node_field` is the hint.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 it will create a new table for the field which is shared between two or more content type.
the field "bundle" will store the content type
"entity id" will store the node id of respected node
"field_fieldname_value" will store the value of the filed..